# Need to edit background color of a WebPartZone

Tags: web-parts

I am trying to change the color of a WebPartZone on a page from the default of 'white' to transparent. I thought this would be easy to do with CSS but it appears that the background color is defined inline via the WebPartZone and I don't know where to go to edit that. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured out to use Firebug to copy the full CSS path to the content area and set 'background-color' to transparent. Worked like a charm.